# How heat is added to a system? Probably a noob question

Tags: thermodynamics

ok so I am literally just getting into thermodynamics, this is literally my first search, what I am wondering is how fundamentally heat is added to a system. For example say I have a flame heating an object at 120 degrees F and I add a second flame beneath the object that is also burning at 120 degrees F, does the total heat applied to the object equal 240 degrees F or is it still 120 Degrees F from a larger source.

Comment: Temperature and heat aren't the same. Each of the two flames heats the system. Use some realistic value  for the flame temperature...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Alchimista temperature and heat are two different things. Temperature is a measure of part of the internal microscopic energy of an object. Heat is defined as energy transfer between objects due to a temperature difference between the objects. So to answer the title of your post heat will transfer to a system (object) if the system is exposed to something that has a higher temperature than the system. But once the temperatures are the same heat transfer stops.

Now everything else being the same, the rate of heat transfer to the system in the cases of heat conduction and convection will be proportional to the magnitude of the temperature difference. So if you double the temperature difference between the heat source and the system you will theoretically double the rate of heat transfer.

Generally, depending on the mass of the system and the heat source, and assuming no system phase changes and no system work, as heat transfers to the system the temperature of the system will rise and the temperature of the source will fall until eventually they both reach the same temperature somewhere between their original temperatures. The two objects are then said to be in thermal equilibrium with each other and heat transfer ceases.

Beyond that if you are really interested in learning more take a course and/or get a good textbook on thermodynamics.

Hope this helps as a primer.

Comment: If heat itself is a "transfer" why do you say "heat is being transfered"? It is like saying energy transfer is transfered. Better choice of words is I guess "as the system is being heated".

Comment: @ŽarkoTomičić As I explained below the term "heat transfer" is somewhat a misnomer, as the second term is redundant.  But when the term is used it is intended to mean energy transfer due to temperature difference. That's a mouthful to say each time we refer to  heat. Grammar aside, as I explained below it is never meant to say there is a substance called heat that is part of the internal energy of a system.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how many heat sources you use that are all 120 degrees F, once the object being heated reaches 120 degrees F, it will be at equilibrium with the heat sources and will not get hotter.

Answer (score -1):

Internal miccroscopic energy of the system is stored in particles kinetic and potential energy. So if object is bigger it has more particles and so every inidividual particle needs to move slower to have the same amount of total kinetic energy. Energy per particle is directly connected to temperature. So when an object is at 120 degrees and the other object is at 100 degrees it means they will exchange their internal energies but the one at 120 will give more of its internal energy then it receives. Tempreture also can be thought of as readiness of an object to give away its internal energy. Part that is being transfered is called heat. An object which does not give away any heat and can only receive is said to be at absolute zero. So, if you have two flames each at 120 they will heat an object two times faster but to a 120 degree at which point readiness of that object is equal to readiness of your heat sources so the object gives away about the same amount as it receives. So no more increase in internal energy or temperature.

Comment: Heat is not kinetic energy stored in things. That’s internal energy. Heat is defined as energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. Things do not possess heat. Now you can think about heat as transferring microscopic kinetic energy from a high temperature object to a lower temperature object. But it is not the kinetic energy itself

Comment: I did not say that it is stored in things I wrote that it is stored in movement of particles id est, we associate heat which of course is the part of internal energy being transfered, to or with kinetic energy of the particles. For a free, ideal gas, its total internal energy is only kinetic, so you can directly associate this with temperature. Heat is not the transfer itself, it is a part of internal energy that is transfered because of temperature difference. But if you want to magine, microscopicaly, how this transfer is happening, you can imagine collisions betwen particles...

Comment: Heat is not stored in particles. Heat is not part of internal energy that is transferred. To better understand heat I suggest you check out the Hyperphysics website

Comment: Ok, let me repeat: I said that it is associated with kinetic energy of the particles, not in them. So i meant that it is actually the movement of the particles. As I see it you hae heat and you have transfer of heat. Internal energy of the system is the total kinetic and potential energy of its constituents and heat is one part of it, part that is transfered because of temperature difference. How does a body with higher temperature and same internal energy look like under the microscope? Its molecules are moving faster. That is the picture i was trying to paint.

Comment: As you yourself said, heat will transfer....you did not write heat is going on. If you wrote "will transfer" it had to be somewhere before it is transfered, waiting to be transfered.

Comment: “Internal energy of the system is the total kinetic and potential energy of its constituents and heat is one part of it”. Let’s consider this statement.  Suppose we have an ideal gas in an insulated cylinder and allow it to expand adiabatically. The gas (system) does work.  Per the first law $\Delta U=Q-W$ and since the expansion is adiabatic, $Q$ =0. For an ideal gas we have $\Delta U=C_{V}\Delta T$. There is a decrease in temperature and thus a decrease in internal energy. If heat is a part of the internal energy, where did the heat go?

Comment: Of course the reason the internal energy decreased is because the gas did work. 
So are we now to say that work is also a part of the internal energy of the gas? If that’s the case, what part of the internal energy is work and what part is heat?  The answer is neither.  Work and heat are processes that can either increase or decrease internal energy. Once the energy transfer occurs by either process, that energy can no longer be associated with the terms heat or work. The effects of the two types of transfers are indistinguishable.

Comment: If a gas temperature increases or decreases we have no way of knowing if it was because of heat or work. Now the term “heat transfer” is admittedly somewhat of a misnomer. If heat is energy transfer, the term becomes “energy transfer transfer”.  The second transfer is redundant. When the term is used it is intended to mean energy transfer due to temperature difference.

Comment: To sum it up, there is not a substance called “heat” that an object contains as part of its internal energy and that can be transferred to another object.  That’s the caloric theory of heat that was debunked 175 years ago by James Joule.

Comment: I did change my answer as you could probably see. Just to be clear, when I say heat I actually mean kinetic energy of particles that is being transfered because of the collisions. So in a way, I associate heat with the kinetic part of the energy of the system.

Comment: The revision in an improvement, but I'm afraid you still can't associate heat with only the kinetic energy part of the internal energy of a system, and here's why. Heat can be added or removed from a system undergoing a phase change. It's called the latent heat of fusion or latent heat of vaporization. A phase change occurs at constant temperature. There is no change in the kinetic energy component of the internal energy of the system. The change is in the potential energy of the system. So heat is not unique to kinetic energy changes.

Comment: Well, if there is heat being transfered during some phase change like from solid to liquid then kinetic energy of one system (heater) is used to cause changes in another like breaking chemical bonds...so of course there is no change in temperature....i guess.

Comment: Not sure I follow you. We are talking about the effect of energy transfer by heat on the system and in the case of phase change of the system only the potential energy component of the system increases or decreases when it is a constant temperature phase change. Not sure what the source has to do with it.  But I can even conceive of an example when there is no change in kinetic energy of the source either.

Comment: Suppose the source of the energy transfer is a two-phase liquid vapor system. I place the source in contact with a lower temperature two-phase liquid solid system. The energy transfer out of the source converts vapor to liquid at constant temperature.  That same energy transferring into the liquid-solid system converts solid to liquid, again at constant temperature.  The kinetic energy of neither system changes.

Comment: If vapor is converted to liquid you say there is no change in kinetic energy?

Comment: Yes that's correct for a constant temperature phase transistion. For example, at 1 atm pressure water vapor (steam) at 100 C condenses to liquid water at 100C. It is a constant temperature process. The two phases coexist at the same temperature while phase change occurs. No change in kinetic energy. I'm sorry but I have no more time to devote to this discussion.